# Can't run the ls command on the root directory without using sudo

Tags: linux, sudo, centos-7, ls

CentOS 7.6.180
GNOME-CLASSIC 3.28.2

I've always been able to run ls on the / directory in the system above.

Now it just hangs when I run ls.  Same if I try to see the / dir with software other than the terminal.

However, I can successfully run ls on the / dir is I use sudo.

This change happened after I cancelled a large rsync job in the / dir ( ctrl c ) and issued a reboot -f command.

I don't know if those things are the cause.

How can I restore the ability to read the / directory with ls?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say exactly what will solve the problem but it is likely your filesystem has been corrupted, possibly some information containing file permissions which is why root can see everything but another user hangs. It is not 100% sure since I do not have access to your filesystem obviously but *ls* is should not hang. If you do not have permissions for something, it should fail immediately rather than hang.

The most likely way to solve this is to repair the file system. Given that the root file system is mounted when the system boots, you have to do this from an operating system running on a different disk. If you have a dual-boot system, then use the other OS. Otherwise, there are many *Linus Rescue* images that can be burned into a CD or written to a USB key. You then boot from that and use a shell to do a filesystem check. The general form of the command is:

```
fsck [options] /dev/<DEV>
```

Replace `<DEV>` above with the device partition on which the root filesystem is mounted, usually something like `nvme0n1p1` or `sda1`. Without any options fsck may not do anything, so you can add `-a` for automatic repair, `-f` to force the repair when fsck reports the filesystem is marked clean, `-y` to accept automatically all repair options, in case there are lots of errors.

The exact command depends on the fileystem, so check the man page before to confirm these options apply to you. There are specialized fsck versions for many file systems, for example:

```
fsck.jfs
```

For JFS which add an option to get the journal from a separate device.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved itself.

I connected back to that computer this morning.

The problem was gone.

My theory is that the "cancelled" rsync still had something running, something was blocking ls from operating on /

Thanks much for responding.